# How to display a raw image file in a Qt GUI?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to C++ and Qt but I was wondering if anyone could help me.

I have a raw image file named `fb0` with the following properties:

```
Width: 1024
Height: 768
Format: rgb565 (QImage::Format_RGB16?)
```

How would I go about loading the data from `fb0` and then displaying this image in a Qt GUI?

**Solution:**

```
   QFile file("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\RawImage.raw");
   if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
   {
       qDebug("Could not open file");
   } else {
       qDebug() << file.fileName() << " opened";
   }
   QByteArray array =file.readAll();
   unsigned char* Data = (unsigned char*)&array.data()[0];
   QImage myImage(Data,1024,768,QImage::Format_RGB16);
   QLabel myLabel;
   myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
   myLabel.show();
```

Comment: Does Qt even support rgb565? Raw images usually come rgb888... If so you can just construct the image from a raw char *.

Comment: [link](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qimage.html)

**QImage::Format_RGB16 - The image is stored using a 16-bit RGB format (5-6-5).** ??? I dono...

Comment: In that case `QImage::QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format )` should work just fine.

Comment: Any Idea how i could load the file into a uchar variable? lol

Comment: usually RAW file formats as taken from a camera of RGB888 format, not necessarily RGB565. Tho that is easily tested once you get everything else working.

Comment: Please don't add a solution to the question @Scott. You are free to make that an actual answer. Please post it as such if that is what ended up solving your problem.

Comment: Scott, Bart is right. Please edit your question, remove the solution, and post it as a separate answer. On SO, you're more than welcome to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
QFile file("yourFile.raw");
if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) return;
QByteArray array = file.readAll();
QImage image(array.data(), w, h, QImage::Format_RGB16);
```

Haven't tested it though. Brain to terminal.

Comment: There is a problem with this though. when using this constructor, QImage does not take ownership of the data pointer, therefore when the QByteArray instance is destroyed, the buffer will be destroyed too, making the QImage instance potentially dangerous to use.

Comment: Doesn't QImage copy the data internally? I don't think it makes sense to share the data in that case. Best case it is reference counted sharing, so the byte array should not delete the data once gone.

Comment: Almost there! It displays the image but it is distorted.

Comment: @Scott - maybe the format is wrong, try others. Either the format or the resolution is off.

Comment: Or maybe the image uses a line stride?

Comment: Without exact format specs one can only guess until it comes out correctly. @ erelender you appear to be correct. @ Scott - you will have to keep the byte array "alive" as long as you need the image"

Comment: @Scott - so maybe an alignment problem, but since it is 16 bit and width is even number it should be well aligned. So maybe it uses a line stride as Sebastian Redl suggested. You have to use the overload that specifies the length of a line: `QImage::QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, Format format )`

Comment: I know im using the right resolution and format. This FFMPEG command works perfectly `ffmpeg -vframes 1 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb565 -s 1024x768 -i fb0 fb0.png`

Comment: @Scott try specifying the line length in bytes, if that doesn't help I am officially out of ideas for now. It is possible that ffmpeg calculates it from the format and width automatically.

Comment: Definitely looks like a stride problem, see how it offsets progressively? Maybe there is some padding in the data?

Comment: But the diagonality does not start at the top right, maybe the width is wrong, seems to me the image is not as wide as you think it is