# Display image from raw bitmap file to bmp file

Tags: qt, bitmap, qimage, qt4.8, qtembedded

I am trying to create a QT application which will display a image (bmp) from a raw bitmap file. The raw bitmap file is of .panel file format. Its in RGB565 format.

How do we use/convert the raw bitmap (img.panel) into a bmp file, so I can use it Qimage.

```
QFile file("/usr/bitmap.bmp");
if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) 
return 0;

QByteArray array = file.readAll();
QImage image((const uchar*)array.data(), h_bitmap, v_bitmap, QImage::Format_RGB16);
image.save("/usr/test_qimg_16.bmp","BMP");
image = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB16);
image.load("/usr/test_qimg_16.bmp");
QPixmap pixmap;
```

This is the image I get after this operation. 
http://tinypic.com/r/kb4pd4/8

But I am expecting something like this : 
http://tinypic.com/r/dptpq1/8

Thank you. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637721/how-to-display-a-raw-image-file-in-a-qt-gui

Comment: Thanks I did the same thing, but my image is distorted. Here is the code
Added the code !!

Comment: Edit your question and add this formatted as code

Comment: Try removing the 16, `int bytesPerLine`, or put 2 (bytes, not bits) so Qt detects it automatically. Also, why load, convert and save again?

Comment: Will try to do it tomorrow. The Color depth is 256, so I am unable to understand which class to use !

Comment: Still the image is distorted. I am using QT for Embedded hardware board. Am I missing any libraries ? JPG display is good, but bmp is bad!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82169/discussion-between-miki-and-vk41286).

Comment: @Miki- I added the screenshots of the image I get. Appreciate any help ?

Comment: give me a link to your original image in format RGB565, so I can test it

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02804374183229949724. This is the .panel file i.e. is the raw file. I am trying to read this file and doing above operation. 

This is the original image file
=======================
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=37294795439804064119


Thanks for helping

Comment: what are width and height of the .panel image?

Comment: @Miki - Its 160 x 128

Comment: I get your same result. But since you have the original jpg file, why don't you use that?

Comment: @miki- our requirement is we have incoming data in this format. JPEG is only for the reference.

Comment: let's continue in chat from now on...